# AS3 - Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a short piece of code I'm making for use of a particle effect library.

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

I originally had my entire code running from Main and it worked fine, when I decided to put it into a "ParticleManager" class I begun getting this error.

The error itself happens here -

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);

    function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //Draws an explosion on to the screen at the position of the mouse click.
        var emitter:Emitter3D = new ParticleExplosion(new Vector3D(mouseX- width/2, mouseY- height/2, 0));
        renderer.addEmitter( emitter );
        emitter.start();
        trace(e);
        trace(renderer.mouseX)
        trace(renderer.mouseY)
    }

}
```

It occurs on the first line there. And I've tried to research it and found this occurs because the stage is not set to anything, but how do I get around that? Why did it work fine running from Main before hand?

Thanks!

Edit - Additional information requested.

The Main class

```
package 
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;

[SWF(width='800', height='600', frameRate='60', backgroundColor='#000000')] 

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var pManager:ParticleManager;

public function Main()
    {
        pManager = new ParticleManager;

    }
  }
}
```

The ParticleManager class, which before was identical just named "Main" and would run from that.

```
package  
{
//Flint imports
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import org.flintparticles.common.emitters.Emitter;
  import org.flintparticles.common.actions.ScaleImage;
  import org.flintparticles.common.events.EmitterEvent;
  import org.flintparticles.common.events.ParticleEvent;
  import org.flintparticles.threeD.emitters.Emitter3D;
  import org.flintparticles.threeD.particles.Particle3D;
  import org.flintparticles.threeD.renderers.BitmapRenderer;
  import org.flintparticles.threeD.renderers.controllers.FirstPersonCamera;
  import org.flintparticles.threeD.zones.LineZone;
  //Flash imports
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
  import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
  import flash.geom.Rectangle;
  import flash.geom.Vector3D;



    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class ParticleManager extends Sprite 
    {
        private var orbitter:FirstPersonCamera;
        private var renderer:BitmapRenderer;


    public function ParticleManager()
    {

    //Sets up the "BitMapRenderer"  a rectangle where the particle effects will be drawn on to
      renderer = new BitmapRenderer( new Rectangle( 0, 0, 800, 600 ), false );
      renderer.x = 0;
      renderer.y = 0;
      renderer.addFilter( new BlurFilter( 2, 2, 1 ) );
      renderer.addFilter( new ColorMatrixFilter( [ 1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.95,0 ] ) );
      addChild( renderer );


      renderer.camera.position = new Vector3D( 0, 0, -400 );
      renderer.camera.target = new Vector3D( 0, 0, 0 );
      renderer.camera.projectionDistance = 400;

      //Mouse click

        function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);
        }


        function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Draws an explosion on to the screen at the position of the mouse click.
            var emitter:Emitter3D = new ParticleExplosion(new Vector3D(mouseX- width/2, mouseY- height/2, 0));
            renderer.addEmitter( emitter );
            emitter.start();
            trace(e);
            trace(renderer.mouseX)
            trace(renderer.mouseY)
        }

    }

    public function removeEmitter( ev:EmitterEvent ):void
    {
      Emitter3D( ev.target ).removeEventListener( EmitterEvent.EMITTER_EMPTY, removeEmitter );
      renderer.removeEmitter( Emitter3D( ev.target ) );
    }

    public function destroy():void
    {
      for each( var e:Emitter in renderer.emitters )
      {
        e.stop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's not added to stage; therefore, stage is null when the code executes.

Listen for added to stage, then execute that code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);
}
```

Previously from your Main, it was probably already added to stage.

From Main, I don't see how the particle manager is added to the display list.  I believe you just need to add your particle manager to Main:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    [SWF(width = '800', height = '600', frameRate = '60', backgroundColor = '#000000')]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var pManager:ParticleManager;

        public function Main()
        {
            pManager = new ParticleManager;
            addChild(pManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With that addition I no longer get the error, flashplayer loads and then just sits with a whitescreen, where as before it would work fine.

Comment: Is there an error?  More than your code excerpt is required to fully understand your implementation.

Comment: There is no error. I have updated my original post to display the full Main and ParticalManager class. Prior to this the ParticalManager class was just the Main class.

Comment: I think you just need to add your particle manager to Main's display list.